# What does setUseClientMode mean

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

When I try to upgrade an exsisting Socket connection to a SSLSocket connection and I set `setUseClientMode(true)` then I get the error `javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 1` when calling `mySSLSocket.startHandshake();`. When not setting `setUseClientMode()` then everything works fine, and I can send and receive messages. I'm not asking for a fix, just what it means and what may be causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It determines whether this side (a) sends or (b) expects to receive the initial handshake message, the `ClientHello`. If `useClientMode` is true, this side sends it. Don't set it at a server unless you really know what you're doing. If you're in a server and you are upgrading an accepted `Socket` you *must* set it to *false.* Otherwise there is really very little occasion to use it at all.

NB `useClientMode=true` is the default.

Comment: why do you _have_ to set it to false when upgrading an existing socket? And in what case would you set it in a server?

Comment: @ConnerDassen That's not what I said. I said you have to set it to false *if you're in a server **and** you're upgrading an **accepted** socket,*, so the `SSLSocket` you are upgrading to has to behave like the server, not like the client. You would set it in a server when and only when you are 100% confident that the client has set it to false, and you would do so because you want the TCP client to authenticate itself rather than the TCP server doing so. This in turn probably means you wrote both ends.

Comment: The client is an android app I develop myself, so the client needs to authenticate anyways.

Comment: @ConnerDassen The TLS server in the 'useClientMode' sense always authenticates itself. It can ask the client for a certificate as well. Client authentication is not in itself not a reason to switch the client modes around, and doing that requires the cooperation of the peer to work. You didn't have that in your case, and that's why you got the error you're asking about.

Comment: yeah so I added the line setUseClientMode(false) in the peer and now it's working

Comment: If the peer is the client you are doing this back to front, as now the server isn't authenticating to the client.

Answer (score 0):

> setUseClientMode

is not much from what it says. That attribute specify on which side of communication is managing the the sslsocket, [check standard implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.java#SSLEngine.setUseClientMode%28boolean%29) .

Pseudo code for SslSocket Server side:

```
private ServerSocket createServerSocket(InetAddress localIp, int port) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket sock;
    Boolean dataProtection = (Boolean) ctx.getAttribute(FtpConstants.ATTR_DATA_PROT);
    boolean ssl = dataProtection != null && dataProtection;
    if (ssl) {
        SSLServerSocketFactory factory = ctx.getOptions().getSslContext().getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(port, 1, localIp);
        sslServerSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
        enableCipherSuites(sslServerSocket);
        sock = sslServerSocket;
    } else {
        sock = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port, 1, localIp);
    }
    sock.setSoTimeout(DATA_CHANNEL_TIMEOUT);
    return sock;
}
```

pseudo for client side:

```
public void test_UseClientMode() throws Exception {
    SSLServerSocket sss = getSSLServerSocket();
    sss.setUseClientMode(false);
    assertFalse(sss.getUseClientMode());
    sss.setUseClientMode(true);
    assertTrue(sss.getUseClientMode());
}
```

So in the end your handshake error is telling you the actor is having the wrong message type during handshake parsing :

```
if (state >= type
                && (type != HandshakeMessage.ht_hello_request)) {
            throw new SSLProtocolException(
                    "Handshake message sequence violation, " + type);
        }
```

where [ht_hello_request](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage.java) is the first message that's coming in the starting communication, which has been unexpected type from current actor's communication side.

Comment: 'Is not much from what it says' is meaningless, and there is no such thing as 'which side of communication is managing the `SSLSocket`'. Each side is managing its own, and can't even see the other side's, if indeed there even is one: it could be OpenSSL for example.

Comment: Isn't what I meant.  'which side of communication is managing the SSLSocket'  got to be read in function of the context. So if you're on Server side or Client side...that was implicit.

Comment: There is no 'context' in which either of the statements I mentioned makes any sense. This all just meaningless waffle.

Comment: I think its not. Especially for pseudo code, and link to actual source code, my answer is specific and clearer than yours. Taking out a phrase without reading whole post is not the right way to learn from the community. I strongly discourage your way of act.

Comment: Baffling. There is nothing 'specific' or  correct or even meaningful about 'which side manages the `SSLSocket`', and stating that it is about which side sends the `ClientHello` message is *extremely* specific. Nothing was taken 'out of context'. If it isn't what you meant, fix your answer. We can't read your mind.